# mobx computed / reactive context with event handlers?

Tags: javascript, mobx

With MobX, `@computed` properties are only cached when accessed from an `observer` or reactive context.  So for example:

```
class Foo {
    @computed
    get somethingExpensive() { return someReallyExpensiveOperation() }
}

const f = new Foo();
setInterval(() => console.log(f.somethingExpensive), 1);
```

Will always call `someReallyExpensiveOperation()` because the `computed` is being called outside of a reactive context.

Is there a way to "enter" a reactive context to gain the benefits of `@computed` for `setTimeout` callbacks, `EventEmitter` event handlers etc?

EDIT: Another way to put this.. if I change the decorator to

```
class Foo {
    @computed({ requiresReaction: true })
    get somethingExpensive() { return someReallyExpensiveOperation() }
}
```

..it will throw when accessed from the `setInterval` example.

Comment: Have you stumbled upon [this issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1332)?

Comment: I have.. I don't think it's the same issue.   They're asking about keeping it alive.. in my case the @computed is never cached in the first place.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Not confidently, no.   Triggering a `reaction` works, but is kludgy.  Been meaning to experiment with wrapping the event handler in an `action`.   Let me know if you discover anything.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I use an instantly disposed [`autorun`](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html):

```
autorun((reaction) => {
    console.log(f.somethingExpensive)
    reaction.dispose()
})
```

---

Also made a npm [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx-run-in-reactive-context):

```
import runInReactiveContext from 'mobx-run-in-reactive-context'

// ...

runInReactiveContext(() => {
    console.log(f.somethingExpensive)
})
```